# How To Target a <div> inside an <iframe> using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

in our user control, for web app, what we do is we actually use Javascript to render a list of twitter feeds as suggested by Twitter
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

However, we want to do some customization, like removing the avatar and a few other things.  Here is the sample snippet

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px;" title="Twitter Timeline" width="300" height="381">

<html><head><style type="text/css">body{display:none}</style><base target="_blank"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://platform.twitter.com/embed/timeline.633fdd7a8cbe780bedb23434c948fe33.default.css">


<div class="timeline-footer" data-scribe="section:footer">
  <a class="tweet-box-button web-intent" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=TheMarilynShow" data-scribe="element:timeline_permalink">Tweet to @TheMarilynShow</a>
</div>
</div></body></html>
</iframe>
```

Now, let's say if I want to do CSS styling to the div  class="timeline-footer", would that be possible this  is hosted by Twitter, not us.  would it be possible to do it on our client code using JQuery to target it?

Please advise.

Comment: You can try CSS if you know the classes being used and you can send postmessages to an iframe which you can receive and handle inside the iframe, but  you have no control on the iframe content other than that.

Comment: Why don't you judt use a 3rd party plugin like [hellojs](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) to fetch data via json and build the ui like you neef?

Comment: Is the iframe URL in the same domain as the main document ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery to target this .... you only need to use a good and robust CSS selector, All you need is to trace his class names and make more efficient selectors like:

```
#twitter-widget-0 .timeline-footer {
  ...../*your properties*/
}
```

*PD: also as a last resource make use of `!important` declaration.*

Answer (score 0):

To access elements inside an iframe using jQuery you can add a `name` attribute to the iframe e.g. `<iframe name="iframe1"></iframe>` and use

```
$('div.timeline-footer', window.frames["iframe1"].document).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

This assumes that your iframe src is on the same domain/port/protocol as the parent window. Otherwise this is not possible

Comment: no, IFRAME is on a different domain. It is hosted by Twitter, not us.